# Magento 2.1.X USPS API First Class No Longer Working

Tags: magento-2.1, usps

Someone already asked this questions about Magento 1.9.3.4, and can be found at the following link [Magento 1.9.3.4 USPS API First Class No Longer Working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191492/magento-1-9-3-4-usps-api-first-class-no-longer-working)

I tried following the steps found on that question and the steps linked to from that post at the [blog.shipperhq.com site](http://blog.shipperhq.com/2017/09/usps-api-changes-sept-1st-2017/) and couldn't get the first class option working again.

The steps found at the blog.shipperhq.com mentioned for Magento 2.0.X you should edit the following file, **vendor/magento/module-usps/Model/Usps.php** but I'm running Magento 2.1.5 and don't have that file.

Does anyone have the proper steps for a workaround that work with Magento 2.1.X? For more context about the issue, please click the link at the top of my question.

Comment: Anyone? Please? I'm running an online retail business that gets 10 to 20 orders a day typically and my orders have been dropping ever since First Class shipping is no longer available. I can't believe Magento has not put out a patch or fix for this issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

Edit vendor/magento/module-usps/Model/Carrier.php instead Usps.php
Here is the workaround http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/tech_bull_USPS-patch-Sept2017.html